# twitter/tweepy filter tweets that start with a given string

Tags: twitter, filter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy stream api now.

I can filter the keyword use the `stream.fileter(track=[])` method.

I also want to filter the tweets that starts with a given string.

But he method `stream.filter(track=['H'])` won't match the tweet `'Hello'`

Can i do that and how to do it?

Comment: You just can't do it. Take a look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) to see what you can and can't do. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Irnzcig is correct, that kind of restrictions aren't available through twitter Streaming API. What you can do is open a connection to receive all the allowed tweets and filter yourself the ones that start with `H`

To be more specific, however, [Streaming API request parameters](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters) is what you're looking for. The link provided in the comment is for the Rest API, while they operate on somewhat similar query input they're vastly different.